# Could not create query metamodel on simple JPA repository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I defined the following repository

```
public interface CityVerboseRepository extends JpaRepository<CityVerbose, Integer>{
    List<CityVerbose> findByStreetStartingWith(String street);      
}
```

corresponding to the entity

```
@Entity
public class CityVerbose {
    @Id
    public Integer id;

    public String street;
}
```

but all I am getting is

> could not create query metamodel for method public abstract
>   java.util.List

once I am trying to autowire that repository. All my other repositories work just fine...

Comment: I guess you are using spring data jpa?

Comment: yes Version 1.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: Can you please add the full stacktrace?

Comment: sure, added the stack trace

Comment: Have you tried to rename your interface to `CityVerboseRepositoryCustom`?

Comment: but it is not a customer repository, isn't it? The Custom Repository issue, that needs exact naming convention only applies if I am actually implementing the interface, but not if I am just extending it. but sure I try

Comment: mh it seems like he does not understand StartingWith

Comment: 1.0.1 does not support that in the jpa repo. updated and worked fine :( removed the stacktrace for cleanup

Comment: Rename your method to findAllxxx if you want to return a collection for consistency reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `startingWith` syntax is not available in 1.0.3.RELEASE of spring data. Updated to 1.2.0.RELEASE and everything worked fine