# Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.Optional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle, spring-data-jpa

After struggling with library versions, I've gotten to a point where I'm stuck. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482593/could-not-create-query-metamodel-on-simple-jpa-repository) didn't seem to apply, as it's three years old and I'm using much newer versions of things, and it's complaining about `Optional<>`. My Gradle file: https://github.com/JetForMe/spring-hoa/blob/master/build.gradle?ts=4

```
public
interface
UserRepository
    extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
{
    Optional<User>              findByLogin(String inLogin);
}
```

for the entity

```
@Entity public class User
{
    public
    User(String inLogin, String inClearPassword)
    {
        mLogin = inLogin;
        mEncryptedPassword = inClearPassword;       //  TODO
    }

    public  Long            getId()                     { return mId; }
    public  String          getLogin()                  { return mLogin; }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long                    mId;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String                   mEncryptedPassword;
    public String                   mLogin;
}
```

Full log:

```
$ gradle bootRun
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:bootRun
Oct 25, 2016 4:10:55 AM com.latencyzero.hoa.Application main
INFO: Launched!
Oct 25, 2016 4:10:56 AM com.latencyzero.hoa.Application main
INFO: Launched!
2016-10-25 04:10:56.857  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@62419c38: startup date [Tue Oct 25 04:10:56 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-25 04:10:57.125  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a730500e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2016-10-25 04:10:57.334  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] com.latencyzero.hoa.Application          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-10-25 04:10:57.343  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1b543bc9: startup date [Tue Oct 25 04:10:57 PDT 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@62419c38
2016-10-25 04:10:58.512  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]]
2016-10-25 04:10:58.691  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2016-10-25 04:10:58.761  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2016-10-25 04:10:58.766  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository.
2016-10-25 04:10:58.847  WARN 1142 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-10-25 04:10:59.062  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=f74c8b81-5f49-333e-bb6b-335bfdc05d6d
2016-10-25 04:10:59.181  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b164d11] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-10-25 04:10:59.226  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a730500e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-10-25 04:10:59.740  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-10-25 04:10:59.757  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-10-25 04:10:59.759  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2016-10-25 04:10:59.860  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-10-25 04:10:59.860  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2517 ms
2016-10-25 04:11:00.203  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.204  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.204  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.204  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.204  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.206  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.206  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.206  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.206  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.208  INFO 1142 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.666  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-10-25 04:11:00.680  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-10-25 04:11:00.747  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2016-10-25 04:11:00.748  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-10-25 04:11:00.750  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-10-25 04:11:00.787  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-10-25 04:11:00.986  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2016-10-25 04:11:01.309  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.latencyzero.hoa.User (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2016-10-25 04:11:01.385  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-10-25 04:11:01.393  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-10-25 04:11:01.434  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-10-25 04:11:01.675  WARN 1142 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [/Users/rmann/Projects/HOA/spring-hoa/build/classes/main/com/latencyzero/hoa/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository.findByLogin(java.lang.String)!
2016-10-25 04:11:01.675  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-10-25 04:11:01.675  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-10-25 04:11:01.678  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-10-25 04:11:01.682  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-10-25 04:11:01.705  INFO 1142 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2016-10-25 04:11:01.729 ERROR 1142 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [/Users/rmann/Projects/HOA/spring-hoa/build/classes/main/com/latencyzero/hoa/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository.findByLogin(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeay.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at com.latencyzero.hoa.Application.main(Application.java:46) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at lect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository.findByLogin(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DepDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository.findByLogin(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport66) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [login] on this ManagedType [com.latencyzero.hoa.User]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:128) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:113) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:566) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.getTypedPath(JpaQueryCreator.java:334) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:277) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:182) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:109) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:49) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:118) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:241) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 44 common frames omitted


BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 12.328 secs
```

Comment: Remove the `javax.persistence` and `spring-data-jpa` dependency from your gradle build. Those are already managed by the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords** (or save them as plain text), when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Next to that you don't have a field named `login` but a field named `mLogin`. So your `findBy` method should read `findByMLogin` instead of `findByLogin` or rename your fields in your entity.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the name of the method findByLogin with findByMLogin. The pattern used here is findByXXX where XXX is the name of the member field.

Comment: The Bookmark tutorial doesn't use `@Column`, so I'd like to know what I'm missing with respect to that.

Comment: That's right. Perhaps findByMLogin will work?`Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [login]`

Comment: @Ruddy, thank you, that got me a lot farther. It compiles and runs, complains about "MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket" (probably no big deal). But now all requests get a basic auth challenge, and fail because I have no idea what to put in there. If I can't figure that out, I'll ask a new question.

Comment: I tried adding `@Column(name = "login")`, but that results in `Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [login] on this ManagedType [com.latencyzero.hoa.User]`. Changing the instance variable name to `login` (and removing `@Column)` allows it to work, but I'd sure like to name it `mLogin`.

Comment: If you edit your answer to include the `findByMLogin` suggestion, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ruddy, this worked for me! Have a link to any documentation, which justifies this arbitrary pattern? Can't seem to find any...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in `spring-data-jpa` version. In order to use `Optional<>` you need to use `1.6.0.RELEASE` or later. Check this [changelog](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.6.0.RC1/changelog.txt).

Comment: I'm currently using `1.10.4.RELEASE`, so I don't think that's the problem.